# ARKit - place a SCNPlane between 2 vector points on a plane in Swift 3

Tags: swift, scenekit, ios11, arkit

Similar to some of the measuring apps you can see being demonstrated in ARKit, I have a plane with 2 marker nodes on it and a line drawn between the 2. What I need though is an SCNPlane between the 2. So, if your original was the floor and you put a marker either side of a wall, you could represent the physical wall with a SCNPlane in your AR world.

Currently I'm placing the line with the following code:

```
let line = SCNGeometry.lineFrom(vector: firstPoint.position, toVector: secondPoint.position)
let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: line)
lineNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lineNode)
```

lineFrom:

```
extension SCNGeometry {
    class func lineFrom(vector vector1: SCNVector3, toVector vector2: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {
        let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]

        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2])
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)

        return SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])

    }
}
```

I know there are similar questions out there: 35002232 for example. But I think what I'm after is simpler. There is an answer there by a user: Windchill that I can almost get to work with a plane but I can't help but think as the plane is a simpler object, there must be a simple solution.

All I need is for the plane to have a width of the distance between the 2 points, I already know this. and the height isn't important.

Distance calc:

```
let position = SCNVector3Make(secondPoint.position.x - firstPoint.position.x, secondPoint.position.y - firstPoint.position.y, secondPoint.position.z - firstPoint.position.z)
let result = sqrt(position.x*position.x + position.y*position.y + position.z*position.z)
```

Thanks

Comment: I've answered this based on another question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425582/scenekit-shape-between-4-points

Comment: My comment over 6 months ago says that this has been answered by another question I posted. I'll click the solved button though. Should have maybe made it clearer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a node between 2 vectors in ARKit.

See GitHub project here, https://github.com/max6363/ARKit-LineNode-Between-2-Points.

Keep rocking.... Enjoy.... :)

Comment: Does that simply place a line between 2 points? I already had that (see question text). What I was after was a little more complex but I answered it anyway. Thanks