# Scenekit shape between 4 points

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

Given that the route I was taking in a previous question:

[ARKit - place a SCNPlane between 2 vector points on a plane in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264298/arkit-place-a-scnplane-between-2-vector-points-on-a-plane-in-swift-3)

...seems to be flawed, I'm looking at other options. I can draw a line between 2 nodes, I can then create nodes above those, effectively in a square but even if I draw lines between them all, I can't make that into a shape. Is it possible in Scenekit to draw a shape (square) where each of the 4 corners joins to a node.

I can create a plane, position it on a node, transform the pivot and then rotate but it doesn't always work but SCNGeometry lines do.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer, at least my solution is to use SCNGeometry triangles. I wanted a square (rather than a cube) to act as a wall in Augmented Reality so I simply built 2 triangles using the 4 nodes that mapped the 4 corners of a wall.

The class to build the triangle:

```
extension SCNGeometry {

    class func triangleFrom(vector1: SCNVector3, vector2: SCNVector3, vector3: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {

        let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1, 2]

        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2, vector3])

        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)

        return SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    }
}
```

The points for the 2 triangles are [p1, p2, p4] and [p1, p3, p4] called using the following:

```
let thirdPoint = firstPoint.clone()
thirdPoint.position = SCNVector3Make(thirdPoint.position.x, 
thirdPoint.position.y + Float(1.5), thirdPoint.position.z)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(thirdPoint)

let fourthPoint = secondPoint.clone()
fourthPoint.position = SCNVector3Make(fourthPoint.position.x, 
fourthPoint.position.y + Float(1.5), fourthPoint.position.z)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(fourthPoint)

let triangle = SCNGeometry.triangleFrom(vector1: firstPoint.position, vector2: secondPoint.position, vector3: fourthPoint.position)
let triangleNode = SCNNode(geometry: triangle)
triangleNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
triangleNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(triangleNode)

let triangle2 = SCNGeometry.triangleFrom(vector1: firstPoint.position, vector2: thirdPoint.position, vector3: fourthPoint.position)
let triangle2Node = SCNNode(geometry: triangle2)
triangle2Node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
triangle2Node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(triangle2Node)
```

This is all based on creating 2 initial nodes by selecting the bottom 2 points of a wall in ARKit.

Hope that makes sense to anybody else searching for a similar answer.

**EDIT: Adding a Material**

Here's a slightly different extension and the code to add a material to it, the end result of a wall remains the same:

```
extension SCNGeometry {

    class func Quad() -> SCNGeometry {

        let verticesPosition = [
            SCNVector3(x: -0.242548823, y: -0.188490361, z: -0.0887458622),
            SCNVector3(x: -0.129298389, y: -0.188490361, z: -0.0820985138),
            SCNVector3(x: -0.129298389, y: 0.2, z: -0.0820985138),
            SCNVector3(x: -0.242548823, y: 0.2, z: -0.0887458622)
        ]

        let textureCord = [
            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0),
        ]

        let indices: [CInt] = [
            0, 2, 3,
            0, 1, 2
        ]

        let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: verticesPosition)
        let srcTex = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: textureCord)
        let date = NSData(bytes: indices, length: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size * indices.count)

        let scngeometry = SCNGeometryElement(data: date as Data, 
primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.triangles, primitiveCount: 2, 
bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size)

        let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource,srcTex], 
elements: [scngeometry])

        return geometry


    }

}
```

Then simply call it in viewDidLoad() and apply a material

```
let scene = SCNScene()

let quad = SCNGeometry.Quad()

let (min, max) = quad.boundingBox

let width = CGFloat(max.x - min.x)
let height = CGFloat(max.y - min.y)

quad.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "wallpaper.jpg")
quad.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(Float(width), Float(height), 1)
quad.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.repeat
quad.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.repeat

let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = quad
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

sceneView.scene = scene
```

Comment: Thank you, with your extension I created a triangle with three vectors.

Comment: @ondermerol No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: Can you please also show how do i add an image to two SCNGeometry triangles?

Comment: Limited internet for 48 hours or so. You need to add a material to the shape. I’ll be able to put something together over the weekend if you haven’t solved it.

Comment: I've updated my original answer with a solution for applying a material to a wall geometry. If your texture is patterned you may need to play with some of the values to get the correct mapping.

Comment: `SCNGeometryPrimitiveType` also supports `polygon`, so i think there is no need anymore to do it with 2 separate triangles.